# Some properties of Bessel function of first kind with integer order

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

I would like to know the derivation of the following properties of Bessel function of first kind $J_{n}(z)$, where $n\in \{-\infty,\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\dots,\infty\}$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}$,

1. [In this book, page 391](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Astrophysics_of_Cosmic_Rays/x7PvAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=berezinskii%20cosmic%20ray) it has been said that for $z \gg 1$ the dominant harmonics of the Bessel function would be closely spaced about $n\sim z$ and for $z\ll 1$ the dominant harmonics would be $n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2$. Is there any derivation for that?
2. Formula for asymptotic expansion of $J_{n}(n\sin(\theta))$ and $J'_{n}(n\sin(\theta))$ in terms of $K_{\mu}$, modified Bessel function.

Comment: For the second one, see https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.1954.0021 The expansions are in terms of Airy functions which are related to $K_\nu$ (see http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.6.i).